# HTTP headers react-router

Tags: http-headers, react-router

I haven't found an answer to my question so far, so I hope you guys know the answer. I'm looking for an easy way to set http headers within react. To my opinion it would be a nice solution to set them directly inside the router:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

maybe as an attribute or just as an extra tag `<Header>`, so you can easily specify per route which headers you would like to set. For example, for all routes (`path="*"`):

> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com

Just an idea. Is there any module which supports this kind of functionality? Or if that's not the case, is there any reason why not?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done directly within React itself; it must be done on the server hosting the application. Headers can be set for calls within the React app, such as API calls, but not for external calls. React runs applications, but it doesn't host them.